# Typescript: merge 2 interfaces into 1

Tags: typescript

I have 2 interfaces:

```js
export interface UploadAttemptBlocked {
  type: 'UploadAttempt';
  tab_id: string;
  blocked: true;
}

export interface UploadAttemptAllowed {
  type: 'UploadAttempt';
  tab_id: string;
  blocked: false;
  filepath: string;
}
```

When `blocked: true` I don't need `filepath` in the interface. When `blocked: false` the `filepath` should be there.

How can I merge these 2 interfaces into 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for can't be done with the interfaces, however, it is possible to do with types. It is called [discriminated union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).

Let's have a separate type for the common fields:

```
type UploadAttemptCommonFields = {
  type: 'UploadAttempt';
  tab_id: string;
};
```

Now, the `UploadAttempt` type should look like this:

```
type UploadAttempt = UploadAttemptCommonFields & (Blocked | Unblocked)
```

Note that the parenthesis is important to ensure the correct priority order since we want to have a *union* between `Blocked` and `Unblocked`.

The final type:

```
type UploadAttemptCommonFields = {
  type: 'UploadAttempt';
  tab_id: string;
};

type UploadAttempt = UploadAttemptCommonFields &
  (
    | {
        blocked: true;
      }
    | {
        blocked: false;
        filepath: string;
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

While wonderflame's answer is correct, for the sake of completeness I would like to point out that you could also use interfaces as your "discriminator building block":

```js
interface UploadAttemptBase {
    type: 'UploadAttempt';
    tab_id: string;
    blocked: boolean;
}

export interface UploadAttemptBlocked extends UploadAttemptBase {
  blocked: true;
}

export interface UploadAttemptAllowed extends UploadAttemptBase {
  blocked: false;
  filepath: string;
}

type UploadAttempt = UploadAttemptBlocked | UploadAttemptAllowed;
```

Comment: Thanks for adding up, but in the end anyway you are using a `type`